# traversing dom using javascript or RegEx

Tags: javascript, regex

i have innerHTML dom string and i want to print or fetch node value using javascript DOM API or JavaScript RegEx.

```
"<nobr>
<label class="datatable-header-sortable-child" onmousedown="javascript:giveFeedback('dtl_body_',6,event);" onmouseup="javascript:sortTable('dtl_body_',6,event);">Name<img id="dtl_body_img_6" src="xyz.jpg">
<input id="dtl_body_cmp_6" value="compareCaseInsensitiveStrings" type="hidden">
</label>
</nobr>"
```

this is my try.  i have a table so cells[i] is table cell with for loop.
it check for every cell.

```
if(cells[i].childNodes[0].innerHTML.replace(/(\r\n|\n|\r)/gm ,"").trim() == "Name")
    {
    /*Do SomeThing */
    }
```

is there any way to get nodevalue or any RegEx suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Document Fragment [0] to create a DOM using javascript, then use querySelector,querySelectorAll,getElementById etc. method on it to fetch value. In your case it would be following.

```
var docFrag = document.createDocumentFragment();
var divWrapper = document.createElement('DIV');
divWrapper.innerHTML='<nobr>'+
    '<label class="datatable-header-sortable-child"  onmousedown="javascript:giveFeedback(\'dtl_body_\',6,event);" onmouseup="javascript:sortTable(\'dtl_body_\',6,event);">Name<img id="dtl_body_img_6" src="xyz.jpg">'+
     '<input id="dtl_body_cmp_6" value="compareCaseInsensitiveStrings" type="hidden">'+
     '</label>'+
      '</nobr>';
   docFrag.append(divWrapper);
   console.log(docFrag.querySelector('input').value)
```

[0] https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/DocumentFragment

Answer (score 0):

You don't want the `innerHTML`, you want the text content, which conveniently enough is named `textContent`.

```
cells[i].childNodes[0].textContent.trim() == "Name"
```

Should do the trick

Comment: but it is not working on  IE11 . i think trim() not supported if i use replace() still same issue.

Comment: or sometime my childNodes[i] have empty node so IE > 8 givers empty text problem